# Get Selected Value from JXTreeTable

Tags: java, object, selected, tablemodel, jxtreetable

I am building a `treetable` using `JXTreeTabble` and I want to disable/able `menu` items depending on the selected value. So, I tried to put this code in my `table model`:

```
public Object getValueAt(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < root.getSize()){
            return root.get(index);
        }

        return null;

    }
```

**The problem**

The above only works if the contents of the `table` are not expanded. Because the `index` of the `selected row` might be larger than the `size` of the t`able model` (model can have two items and row can have 10 when everything is expanded). Also, the `object type` of the `parent` is different from the `children` (think of a book with chapters as it children).

**What would you suggest as a way to do the above correctly?**

Answer (score 7):

assuming `index` is your row number, try the following to get hold of the node object:

```
TreePath path = treetable.getPathForRow(index);
Object node = path.getLastPathComponent();
```

where `treetable` would be a pointer to the table using this table model.

Answer (score 1):

at JXTreeTable you could access value based on row and nodeClass from your treeTable.
example:

```
int row=treeTable.getSelectedRow();
//get value from column
Object object= treeTable.getValueAt(row, yourColumn);
TreePath path= treeTable.getPathForRow(row);
Object o= path.getLastPathComponent();
Class<? extends Object> entity=o.getClass();
```

the result you would get an Class from the object, you could parse the object to get the value

Answer (score 0):

The indexes may differ in the view and the model. You have to adjust the selected row's index first using `convertRowIndextToModel()`